# Multi-client sockets in Java?

Tags: java, sockets, client

Soon I will be finished with a single-client chat system as a recreational personal project, and I was wondering...  Is it simple to convert something like this to have multiple clients, or would it require a large rewrite?

And in either case, how would you do it? Please be descriptive! :D
Thanks!

Also, how do you transmit files across a socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be simple to convert a single client to multiple clients. It depends on how you have written your application.  Since you are rewriting an application which has been written many times before, I assume you are not afraid to rewrite code and you are doing it to as a learning exercise.

The simplest change would be that where you accept() one client now, you should use a loop to accept many clients. (and pass processing that client to another thread).

To transfer a file over a socket you need to be able to connect to the server as you do now, read the file and send the contents to the server. Instead of passing text chat messages to the receiver, you pass a file message with the contents of the file.

Comment: Thanks!  So, to make it multi-client, I have one thread to accept the clients, and another to handle communication?  And does that mean I can just use the normal thread for the communication and an extra one for accepting clients, or do I have to instantiate two threads?

Comment: You can use two threads per connection but for chat you only need one.

Comment: Also, how do I stop one of the threads, the client-accepting thread, while it is doing `accept()`?  I can't just make the `while` loop have a condition, since it waits until it has a connection.  Do I have to fake a connection to be able to quit the thread?

Comment: When you close the ServerSocket any thread waiting on accept will throw an IOException to indicate it has been closed.

Answer (score 2):

If you are considering writing an IM system then I'd suggest you to work with a more higher level [protocol and API like Jabber/XMPP](http://xmpp.org/about/jabber.shtml). [Here is the example](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0542.html) of transferring a file over socket.

Comment: Though it may be better to do that, I'm trying to do it simply with low-level sockets.  The file transfer example was helpful.